# Running VB.Net Windows forms app as 2 different Windows authenticated users to connect to local and remote SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I've inherited a VB.Net Windows forms application that is used across several hundred remote sites. On the remote sites the application connects locally to a local SQL server instance using the currently logged in Windows user at the workstation - this all works fine.

The application however also needs to connect to a remote SQL server - currently this is done using a set of connection strings and sql authentication. The DBA wants to move away from using SQL server authentication and make everything Windows authentication.

Clearly, adding hundreds of users to the remote DB is not an option. Therefore I need to be able to use the currently logged in user if connecting locally to a local SQL server and a different Windows users (which will have permissions to the db server) if I am connecting remotely.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how this can be done or can suggest an approach.

Thanks

Comment: Are both servers on the same domain?

Comment: @HardCode, yes both servers are on the same domain

Answer (score 0):

Since both servers are on the same domain, create Active Directory Groups for the application, put the users' Windows logins into the groups, and then give the 2, 3 or 10 or whatever app-specific AD groups permissions in the databases. If you're using stored procedures, create a database role for each AD group, grant the DB role execute permissions, and add the AD groups to the DB roles.

Comment: It is an option. Unfortunately, as that many people come and go I don't think we would have the time to keep adding and removing the users from the groups. For me, this might work if we could get the remote connections to connect as one of a set of users in a group (where those users are pre-defined)